# Work library is empty after compiling Verilog source file in Modelsim

Tags: verilog, modelsim

How I can solve this problem: my Work library is always empty after compiling a selected file in Modelsim?

[image]

Comment: Updated answer:  This problem happened to me because my module name was actually the same as another file I compiled. Fixing the names fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

From your screenshot it seems that you haven't saved the file - are you sure you saved your file before compiling? Else ModelSim might be simply compiling an empty file - which would, of course, yield nothing to add to a library.

If that's not the case, try this:

1. Delete old `work` library.
2. Use `File > Change Directory` to change to your working directory.
3. Go to `File > New > Library` and create a new library named `work`. This should create a new directory called `work`.
4. Re-create your Verilog file/project and **make sure it is in the same directory as the library you just created** (not the `work` directory created in step 3, but your working directory)
5. Compile, and it should work

Comment: it still empty  !!

Comment: Sorry to hear that, have you checked your working directory? Your *.v file has to be in the same directory as the library; from your screenshot it seems you are compiling a file from another directory. Your working directory should look something like this:
`Working Directory` contains the file `project.v` and the directory `work` of the library you created as described in step 3.